# Searching a directory, finding the last entered file name in C++

Tags: c++, file, winapi, mfc, directory

I am using Cfilefind library in C++, to get the name of the last entered file to the directory. In other word the file who entered the directory after the existing files.

```
   CFileFind finder;
   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile("*.png");
   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
      cout << (LPCTSTR) finder.GetFileName() << endl;
   }
```

This code works without downloading different library. It gives you all of the file names existing in that time. However it doesnt give them with the order I want to since I want them to be ordered depending on its entering time to the directory. What method in that class should I use and how?

this is the library, I mentioned:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ww9sye6t(v=vs.80).aspx

I also used this method to get the value of int pro value, however it probably gives the entry in alphabetic order and not the last entry value:

```
string processName(int pro)
{
   int count=0;
   string name;
   CFileFind finder;

   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile("*.png");
   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
      count = count + 1;
      if (count == pro){
          name = (LPCTSTR) finder.GetFileName();
          bWorking=false;
      }

   }
   return name;
}
```

As another useful heuristic method I wrote is to to take the number of files existing in that folder, I look the change by that way but it doesn't solve my problem at all. You can also propose a algorithm if possible,

Comment: As another proposed way I can take the values and store them in a array, when the size changed of that array (when a other file enters), I can store them in other array so that I can look at the difference values, but it would take too much time for high number of files, to compare which doesnt exist in the previous array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CfileFind::GetCreationTime()`, that's documented in the link you've given, to get the creation time of each file, and order the files by their creation times.

Comment: yes you probably right but, it takes two parameters, I am new in C++ what does it takes? Can you give an example? or how should I implement it?

Comment: The documentation link you gave explains what parameters it takes, and there's even a link to an example. As a new C++ developer, the most important skill for you to learn is how to read technical documentation, and understand it. Good luck.

Comment: the reason I asked that is (//  pTimeStamp:
A pointer to a FILETIME structure containing the time the file was created.
// refTime
A reference to a CTime object. ) so why should I enter a time inside that method, to get entrance time the current folder, what is the reason for that??

Comment: The function is asking for a pointer to a FILETIME or a reference to a refTime structure that the function will place the creation time into. It's not asking for the creation time itself, it's going to return the file's creation time in the structure whose pointer or reference you are passing.